# Google Maps v3 - update markers on dragging

Tags: jquery, google-maps, maps

When I drag the marker of my own location it should update other markers, since I work with a radius. So if I drag my location around, it should delete markers that are outside of the radius and add markers inside the radius. It does this, but it keeps adding the same markers for like 8 times or so, and of course nobody wants that.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[0]) 
        {
            $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
            ownlat = marker.getPosition().lat();
            ownlng = marker.getPosition().lng();
            clearOverlays(); //deletes old markers
            getevents(); //adds new markers  
        } 
    }   
});
```

});

Comment: What happens in `getevents()`? I guess the 8x repeating is there

Comment: getevents() is also used on on other events (like change radius or click button) and it all works fine there.

Comment: Nevermind, I already got it.
In the eventlistener I should have set the event on 'dragend' instead of 'drag'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API docs state that the 'drag' event fires repeatedly while the marker is dragged. So I figured it's calling `getevents()` quickly several times in a row.

You should use 'dragend' instead, with the drawback that it might introduce a delay for markers to appear while the geocoder runs. (If that becomes a problem, try leaving getevents outside the geocoder call?)